# updating of records in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

Hello im new in laravel 4.2 and i m making an application in the controllers, i made my own function called c_updateSystemUser($id) and here is the code

```
public function c_updateSystemUser($id)
{
    //
    session_start();
    $getsCapt = $_SESSION["captcha"];


    $rules = array(
        'username'     => 'required|min:2|max:50|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]+$/|exists:dbo_systemusers,SystemUserName,$id',
        'description'  => 'required|min:1|max:100|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]+$/',
        'usertype'     => 'required|numeric',
        'capt'         => 'required|numeric'
    );

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
    // process the inputs given by the user
    if ($validator->fails()) 
    {
        return Redirect::to('viewsu/' . $id)
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
    } 
    else 
    {

            // store the values into the database
            $su = SystUser::find($id);
            $su->SystemUserTypeID       = Input::get('usertype');
            $su->SystemUserName         = Input::get('username');
            $su->SystemUserDescription  = Input::get('description');
            $su->timestamps = false;
            $su->save();

            Session::flash('message', 'Successfully created system user!');
            return Redirect::to('viewsu');
        }
    }
}
```

i wanted this function to be called when the user clicked the update button on my view file but when the button is clicked, it is redirecting to some other page (my create user page) i don't know why
 here is the code of my form in my blade

```
 {{ Form::model($su, array('route' =>array('csu.update',$su->SystemUserID),'method'=>'PUT'))}}

            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('usertype', 'User Type') }}
                {{ Form::select('usertype', [null=>'Please Select user type'] + $sTyp , array('class'=>'form-control'))}}
                {{ Form::label('current' , 'Current Type: (unedited) '.$su->SystemType , array('class' => 'label label-primary')) }}
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('username', 'Username') }}
                {{ Form::text('username', $su->SystemUserName, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('description', 'Description') }}
                {{ Form::textarea('description', $su->SystemUserDescription, array('class' => 'form-control','rows' => '3')) }}
            </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('captcha', 'CAPTCHA image: ') }}
                </br>

                {{ HTML::image('http://localhost:8080/laravel3/app/captcha.php', 'alt' , array( 'width' => 200, 'height' => 35 )) }} </br></br>
                {{ Form::text('capt', Input::old('capt'), array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'enter generated captcha')) }}
            </div>

            {{ Form::submit('Edit System User', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}

{{ Form::close()}}
```

i don't know how to make the form call the function `public function c_updateSystemUser($id)` in my controller

my controller file is called systemUsers.php

any ideas? any help would be appreciated

Comment: could you post your routes?

Comment: `Route::resource('csu','systemUsers@c_storeSU');
Route::get('createsu', 'systemUsers@c_createSystemUser');
Route::get('viewsu','systemUsers@c_viewSystemUser');
Route::get('viewsu/{id}' , array('as' => 'findSU', 'uses' => 'systemUsers@c_editSystemUser'));` here is the route im using

Comment: You don't have a route for handling a put request?

Comment: hmm none i thought this `array('route' =>array('csu.update',$su->SystemUserID),'method'=>'PUT'` would handle it already. sorry im really new to this one

Comment: you would want something like:
Route::put('/doesntmatter', array('as' => 'csu.update', 'uses' => 'myController@c_updateSystemUser'));

Comment: also side note, If I were your boss and knew laravel... I wouldn't accept it. Use the naming conventions provided by laravels docs and PSR standards pls.

e.g no c_updateSystemUser... Instead create a user controller and then have a update(User $user) method with a user bound to the passed parameter.

You could also make use of form Request validation:
http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#form-request-validation

Comment: thaaanks! would put that in mind! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your view name is update and its in `views->csu` folder you can do it like following

```
{{ Form::model($su, array('route' =>array('csu.update.c_updateSystemUser',$su->SystemUserID),'method'=>'PUT'))}}
 #yourentry
{{Form::close()}}
```

Your route should be like following:

```
    Route::resource('csu','systemUsers');
```

In `systemUsers.php` add `c_updateSystemUser($id){}` method.